# Using a Bash Script To Automate Testing of A Prolog File

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

I am in the process of grading student assignments, and wish to automatically run queries on the students database, and print the results of those queries to a file.  The issue that I am running into is that I wish to run the multiple queries, but cannot find a way to just add all the queries I wish as a command line argument.

**Relevant Files**

---

Student Submission of Prolog file:

I cannot show you this code, but the students had to solve 4 problems using Prolog, and I have access to those files.

---

`hw4_autograde.sh` NOTE: The compiler was changed to SWI-prolog, not gprolog.

[image]

---

`testcases.txt`: These are the test cases I wish to run.  They consist of various calls to the 4 rules/'functions' the students solved.

[image]

---

I am able to create and append to the output files, but I need to get my bash script working first, then can add the required code to do that.  Any assistance or a point in the right direction would be most helpful.

I have tried to scrutinize this post, but am struggling to get this working:

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/users-prolog/2013-12/msg00004.html

Thank you.

---

**EDIT:**

The solution described by Paulo Moura in the comments solves this problem, however, in using the logtalk tester, I am coming across issues of using multiple prolog files in subdirectories from within submissions.  I used to get output with the student files working, but now all the tests say crashed, when I used to get passed or failed:  Here is a screen shot of what I am currently getting when running `logtalk_tester -p swi -t 60`:

[image]

Below is a screen shot of what is within a student's subdirectory:

[image]

Here is `tests.lgt`:

```
:- object(tests,
    extends(lgtunit)).

    %Tests for shuffle
    %--------------------------------------------------------
    test(shuff_working) :- 
        {shuffle([a,b,c],[d,e,f],[a,d,b,e,c,f])}.

    test(shuff_wrong, false) :-
        {shuffle([a,b,d],[d,e,f],[a,d,b,e,c,f])}.
    
    test(shuff_wrong_2, false) :-
        {shuffle([d,e,f],[a,b,d],[a,d,b,e,c,f])}.
    
    test(shuff_wrong_3, false) :-
        {shuffle([a,b,c,e],[d,e,f],[a,d,b,e,c,f])}.

    test(shuff_var) :-
        {shuffle(X,Y,[1,2,3,4,5,6])}.

    %--------------------------------------------------------
    %Tests for double

    test(doub_working) :-
        {double([a,b,c],[a,a,b,b,c,c])}.

    test(doub_wrong, false) :-
        {double([a,b,c],[a,b,c,a,b,c])}.

    test(doub_var_1) :-
        {double(X,[a,a,b,b,c,c])}.

    test(doub_var_2) :-
        {double([a,b,c],X)}.


    %--------------------------------------------------------

    %Part 2:  Sudoku Solver
    test(sudoku, false) :- 
        {test0}.
    
:- end_object.
```

Here is `tester.lgt`

```
:- initialization((
    % minimize output to the essential
    set_logtalk_flag(report, warnings),
    % load the student submissions
    logtalk_load(['hw4.pl','sudoku.pl']),
    % load the testing tool
    logtalk_load(lgtunit(loader)),
    % load the tests and run them
    logtalk_load(tests, [hook(lgtunit)]),
    tests::run
)).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Logtalk's testing automation to help performing the grading. First, define the queries as tests. As an example, assume that the students are expected to define `foo/1` and `bar/2` predicates then when called should succeed with the bindings `foo(42)` and `bar(a,d)`. We can then define a `tests.lgt` file with those two tests:

```
:- object(tests,
    extends(lgtunit)).

    test(foo, true(N == 42)) :-
        % call foo/1 in "user"
        {foo(N)}.

    test(bar, true(X-Y == a-d)) :-
        % call bar/2 in "user"
        {bar(X,Y)}.

:- end_object.
```

Assume the students submit their code in `foo.pl` and `bar.pl` files, saved in directories named after the student id. For example:

```
submissions
  id1
    foo.pl
    bar.pl
  id2
    foo.pl
    bar.pl
```

You will also need a `tester.lgt` driver file:

```
:- initialization((
    % minimize output to the essential
    set_logtalk_flag(report, warnings),
    % load the student submissions
    logtalk_load(['foo.pl', 'bar.pl']),
    % load the testing tool
    logtalk_load(lgtunit(loader)),
    % load the tests and run them
    logtalk_load(tests, [hook(lgtunit)]),
    tests::run
)).
```

After copying the `tests.lgt` and `tester.lgt` files into each of the student directories, run the `logtalk_tester` shell script from the `submissions` directory containing the students directories:

```
$ cd submissions
$ logtalk_tester -p gnu -t 60
```

You will get a full report of all failed tests and any broken or timed out student submissions. Post-process the report to what you want. Any failed tests will be prefixed by the student id. Also need some stats report?

```
$ cd submissions
$ logtalk_tester -p gnu -t 60 -f xunit
$ logtalk_allure_report
$ allure open
```

See the [`lgtunit`](https://logtalk.org/manuals/devtools/lgtunit.html) tool documentation for details.

Note that this solution shouldn't require any changes to the student submissions. For other examples of how to test plain Prolog code, see e.g. the `tests/prolog` directory on the Logtalk distribution. This solution will work with all Logtalk supported backend Prolog compilers, including GNU Prolog.

Comment: Thank you for messaging.  When you say define the queries as tests, in what format?  Would the above screen shot of my testing file suffice?  I have spent about a half hour going through the logtalk documentation on the tester (https://logtalk.org/testing.html) and don't fully understand how to implement this.  You mentioned running it on the directory containing the student directories.  Will logtalk figure out where the prolog files are automatically and run them on the student databases?

Comment: I expanded the answer to provide more details on the solution.

Comment: Hi Paulo, this is working very well so far, I looked into documentation for defining tests, but have yet to try it on multiple student directories.  I also must manually inspect predicates of the form `foo(X,Y,[a,b,c,d,e,f]).` which would return values for X and Y.  Is there a testing mechanism that allows for this?  Thank you again for the great detail.  This has been so useful for my work.

Comment: Why "manually inspect"? Can't what you want to verify be accomplished by defining suitable tests that can be automated?

Comment: Apologies, for I am new to prolog, but for instance, there may be a set of permutations X and Y associated with `foo(X,Y,[a,b,c,d,e,f]).` that grow exponentially with the size of the list in the 3rd argument.  I suppose I may just test that it works with specific values of X and Y, but it would add many more tests.

Comment: Additionally, some of the students are timing out, but as I read a message that timeout is not supported.  Is there a build that has timeout functioning to your knowledge?  I switch to swi compiler.

Comment: For the `foo/3` predicate, you will indeed need to add more tests or maybe consider using the QuickCheck support provided by `lgtunit`. For the timeout feature, see the implementation notes on the `logtalk_tester` man page (or https://logtalk.org/man/logtalk_tester.html). On Windows, the Bash shell provided by the Git for Windows installer includes a working timeout utility (but you would need to use the current Logtalk git version).

Comment: Hi Paulo, I am having a bug when I try to introduce 2 files in the tester.  Like in your example, if in the student directories I have 2 prolog files (foo and bar say) the tests return broken rather than calling the additional predicates in the second file.  In the tester file I changed the `logtalk_load(['foo.pl'])` to `logtalk_load(['foo.pl','bar.pl'])` but the tester breaks when I add tests for predicates in bar.pl.

Comment: Breaks how? In my answers, both files are loaded and tests for both are defined. You can always updated the question with the details if they don't fit in a comment.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.  I updated the question with specifics.  I think it has to do with perhaps how I invoke the predicate in the sudoku solver file in tests.lgt.

Comment: But no specifics on the actual issue. You can always run the tests manually by using the `gplgt` integration script and then the query `{tester}` from a student directory. Assuming `test0/0` is a predicate that the students are expected to define in their `sudoku.pl` files, I don't see why that would be an issue. Also, your tests are using unification instead of assertions. That means the tests will pass if the student defines e.g. `double/2` as simply `double(_, _).` Instead of `test(doub_working)` write `test(doub_working, true(D == [a,a,b,b,c,c])` with `D` as the call binding.

Comment: I added more detail, but there isn't much in way of explaining the problem, just showing the command I used and the current broken behavior.  I will look into assertions tomorrow.  Thank you.

Comment: In the answer, you made several references to be using **GNU Prolog**. If that's indeed the Prolog system you and your students are using, why are you running the `logtalk_tester` script using **SWI-Prolog**? I.e. why are you using `logtalk_tester -p swi -t 60` instead of `logtalk_tester -p gnu -t 60`?

Comment: I need to update that.  I mentioned in the comments that I switched to swi. `logtalk_tester -p swi -t 60` used to work for me, but now is resulting in crashes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235413/discussion-between-doug-mcmurray-and-paulo-moura).

Comment: Ok... iff the students also used SWI-Prolog to write their submissions. Can you run the tests manually using the `swilgt` integration script and the `{tester}` query from one of the student directories? That may give you an hint of what's causing the crashes. Otherwise look inside the `logtalk_tester_logs` directory for the cause of the crashes. Possibly a Prolog or Logtalk installation issue.

Comment: Now everything works, and I can use both prolog files.  It was a problem with the installation of SWI-Prolog that was giving me crashes.  Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Good. Then you should accept the answer as solving the question.