# Using Logtalk Timeout function for Testing SWI Prolog Files

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, logtalk

This is follow up post associated with [Using a Bash Script To Automate Testing of A Prolog File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68514037/using-a-bash-script-to-automate-testing-of-a-prolog-file)

Now that I have testing effectively implemented, I wish to add timeout values to the tests, so that if a particular case takes too long, the program can move on to the next student's assignment.

When I use `logtalk_tester -p swi -t 60`, the command successfully runs the tests, but mentions that logtalk will skip the -t 60 timeout flag.  My question is, is there a functioning timeout mechanism for logtalk for **MacOS Big Sur**?  The test evaluation is prefixed by the following warning when I run the above command:

[image]

I checked the manual page (https://logtalk.org/man/logtalk_tester.html) but as I understand, Windows has a workaround for getting timeout to work, but I do not see mention of MacOS.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script man pages includes:

> When the script detects either a timeout or a gtimeout command
> (provided by the GNU coreutils package), it will use it to run each
> test set if the timeout option is set to a value greater than zero. On
> Windows operating-systems, the native timeout command is not usable
> for this purpose.

You can install the GNU `coreutils` package easily on macOS using either MacPorts or Homebrew.

For using individual test specific timeouts (instead of test set timeouts as in your question), see:

https://logtalk.org/manuals/devtools/lgtunit.html#tests-with-timeout-limits

P.S. On Windows, the GNU `coreutils` package is available in the Bash shell provided by the Git for Windows installer.

Comment: Yes, downloading coreutils fixed the issue.  Thank you.